# Cant Load Project Solution with error message VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

can i move solution directory , for unknown reason's i found my project.sln in same project properties

and i want make it for examlpe (with previous directory) direcotry

[Message Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GTgs.png)

is that possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question not clear enough.
but if you want to put your .sln in previous directory, follow this step:
-1) copy new .sln in your desktop

-2) edit it as Notepad++, and find this text / and edit it

> Project("{?????-????-?????-?????-??????????}") = "Your Sln Name", "Your Sln Directory\Your Sln Name.vbproj"

Hope it easy to understand how it work.